How to fill hole in concrete wall
I need to fill these holes, one with the pipes and the other small accidental hole drilled. It is on a second floor and can be reached only by extending something down from the terrace. Need help with the substance to use to fill the hole and ideas on how to do it.


Those don't look like accidental holes.They look like deliberate holes drilled in the wrong place.  What is the wall made of and how were the holes drilled if it's so hard to get to?

Better pic that shows access issue?  Is this pic interior or exterior?

I would use something like DAP 7079808676 Concrete Filler, or any of many similar products sold in stores. It comes in a tube, which should make it easy to apply with a caulk gun and maybe a clear PE tube to reach.
